# What is the right way to make an installer for Linux

Tags: linux, installation

I'm developing an application that runs on the server as a Windows service or a Linux daemon.

It is common to make an installer for Windows using NSIS/WIX/InnoSetup/etc to get an installer as a single EXE/MSI file. The question is that is the common way for Linux to make a such installer?

The installer must get some information from user (configuration settings) and then write files to the target directory, write initial config files, run the service/daemon.

The question is not related to the packages for apt/yum/etc package manager. At this moment I want to make a separate installer that can be user for the different Linux distributives.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that you ask that the installer be aware of distribution-specific things like paths, seeing files and their locations and so on, without wanting to resort to distribution-specific tooling.

I've been personally involved in at least two application domain-specific approaches to build universal installers like that, and know of quite a few others.

All. Of. Them. Failed.

Not fundamentally, mind you, but in raising the level of universal ease of use that reduced the support workload of the community developing them. They excelled at other things - keeping build recipes in one place, offering distro-independent installation prefixes, but they failed at being painless, portable, stable, lower-effort solutions for just installing software.

That mostly stems from differences in tooling and software packaging on different Linux platforms, and to a minute degree in nonstandard locations.

Things do work great when you can just rely on all your software's external dependencies being already installed, most libraries being shipped as part of your software itself and no interaction with the rest of the system. But that's in the end an installer that just unpacks files e.g. into /opt/Matlab, not an installer as you wish to have that respects some system specifics and user settings.

Especially integration of services used to be somewhat tricky - I'm super happy that systemd for all serious user bases¹ puts an end to random scripts somewhere in /etc/init.d that do things in hard to guess (if you don't know typical ordering in the distro you use) orders and without any understanding of dependencies. (Systemd standardized a lot of target and service names, and you can just say that your service is needed by the multi-user target but needs working networking and started sssd first)

So, for dependency and service installation, there's little way around either letting your users do some setup manually.

For application-style software that is "leaves" in a dependency tree, self-contained software packaging is a thing - flatpak is probably the most commonly available approach to that. Sadly, not that useful for services.

---

¹ you can never reach more than 95% of users, no matter what you do and e.g. the vocal anti-systemd user base is very good at overpronouncing their importance. They are a fringe group, not using systemd; focus on supporting the 95%, and let the 1% special interest users adopt your packaging post-installation themselves; they made their own bed, and have no business telling other people to lie in it.
Note that supporting these users, but also these of the 95% that have some other minor special quirk always means you should have "just extract all files into the prefix, and tell the user what needs to be done afterwards, roughly" installer mode. That way, distro experts, special use cases and people using your software in an unpredictable future will not hate you.